# iPhone Development: Importing from a .m file to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, import, implementation

I need to import functions from .m file to another .m file.
If it matters, the first .m file is abc.m and the second one is bca.m

Thanks a lot.

Comment: C functions or Obj C methods?  In the implementation of the same class or a different class?

Comment: If you want the function to be reusable, don't do it this way. Instead, you can put the common functions to one file, and then import it.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to read an "Introduction to Objective-C" book if you are just starting: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
#import "abc.h"
```

To the top of *bca.m*.

Answer (score 3):

```
# import "bca.h"
```

Import the header, not the implementation.